# Can a CAN message have two reliable recipients?

Tags: embedded, can-bus

In my situation multiple modules report their state over a CAN bus to a central processor, which replies and drives them. There's also a supervising processor, which listens in on the CAN bus and analyzes incoming messages from the modules for critically dangerous situations (two different modules reporting activating outputs which are absolutely forbidden from being activated simultaneously).

This all works okay as long as the CAN bus is noise-free.

CAN bus guarantees the recipient to receive a message; the message will be resent if no recipient confirms receiving it. The problem begins if there's more than one recipient and all of them absolutely must receive the message.
If the line is clean, both receive it, confirm it, and everything is okay.
If the message is badly damaged, neither will receive it, and it will be resent. That's okay.
But if the noise on the line is "just on the brink", one of them will receive it, and confirm, and the other will fail to receive it (noise on its end of the bus just minimally worse), and since the sender got the confirmation, the message won't be resent.

Is there a reliable way to assure two different recipients of a message both receive it? ...other than sending two messages with two addresses, specifically? (it's essential that the supervising CPU hears the same messages as the main CPU, not just *similar*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously not.
It fails even in the simple case, that one receiver is shutdown.
There is no possibility for the master to detect this (for this single packet).

You need an *advanced* CAN, with more acknowledge slots, for each recipients one slot.

But you could request that each reciepient has to confirm the message with a unique response message.
So your master can detect by a timeout that not all reciepent received the message.

Comment: Can you elaborate about *advanced CAN*? I have trouble finding anything on that subject.

Comment: Sorry, `Advanced CAN` doesn't exists. But you would need it, if you want to garantee multiple reception

Comment: I'll wait with accepting your answer - maybe someone knows some obscure trick or a chip that *creatively extends* the protocol, but thanks for the info so far.

Comment: As I've researched more: as long as we have an assumption (or verification, say, through 'keep-alive' messages) of presence of all listeners on the bus, CAN protocol has a built-in mechanism to verify all received the frame okay: at the end of the frame there is a bit of confirmation; any recipient upon receiving the frame and checking the checksum, can assert the bit (pull down the bus), which counts as 'demand resend'. That's also why messages should not contain deltas, just absolute values as it is permissible for a message to appear twice - following a resend.

Comment: I read in SO community that, there are no master/slave in CAN Bus but you mentioned master in your post. Could you please elaborate your point

Comment: @John You are right, there is no master/slave concept for the CAN bus, but in this case it's used like a master

Answer (score 4):

There is no way at the CAN layer to detect receipt by more than one module.  You would need to add messages to your communication protocol to confirm receipt if this is absolutely critical.  As mentioned, you could have each module receive the same message and send a unique reply.

Some general thoughts:

1) Are the important messages broadcast periodically?  If so, the recipient could test that the periodicity of the message is correct and fail safely if the period is violated.

2) CAN is a very robust network.  In my many years, I have not seen noise affecting a single node like you described other than when the node was at the end of a exceedingly (and irrationally) long wire.  You are correct to worry about this scenario and design your message format and system to be robust to all CAN failures. Generally, when safety or reliability was paramount, we would have more than one CAN bus communicating the information along with a number of crosscheck messages to verify that not only the path was intact but the device on the other end was operating intelligently.  Our general assumption was that if crosscheck messages were making the trip, then our operational messages were making the trip successfully as well.